# Django updating model has broken the admin

Tags: python, django

I updated my models class called Account. I have removed a field called "user"

Removed this line:

```
user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
```

I then ran **makemigration** and then **migrate** successfully.

When I goto:
http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/reports/account/

I get the below error message:

> Account' object has no attribute 'user'

My question is, how do I update the admin code easily when making structural changes to my models/migration?

My admin.py looks like this:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from .models import Account
from .models import Report

from django.contrib import admin

# Register your models here.

admin.site.register(Account)
admin.site.register(Report)
```

Answer (score 1):

It is a **bit complex** process.

The **easier way** is if you don't have any important data and you are only in development phase, just delete your database, and try makemigrations and migrate after that.

It will work fine.

Comment: What you are doing can you explain?

Comment: Sorry, my bad, I had user in the in my  def __str__(self): return user.username. All fixed thanks for your help

Comment: @ChrisEvans, Nice to hear that you fixed, If the solution helped, please vote up and select the answer. Thanks for all the cooperation.

Comment: @ChrisEvans you can select the answer if it helped.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you probably forgot to remove `user` reference somewhere, possibly in `admin.py`. If you go there, there should be something like this (if not, post yours):

```
@admin.register(Account)
class AccountAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    list_display = ('user', ...)
```

Just remove the `user` from there and you should be good.

Comment: Hey Jahongir Rahmonov, thanks for your response. 

I just added my admin.py to the post. Look a bit different.